# Error occurred while creating/connecting to automation server 0x80131500

Tags: com-interop, progress

Based on the number of matches on Google, this may be a candidate for the Tumbleweed award, but here goes...

I have a DLL written in .Net that is exposed for reverse COM interop.  There are several business objects and one object that exposes a method to call a web service via WSE3.

Using VBScript, all of the objects can be instantiated and used with no problem.  However, I need to use the DLL from Progress.  Doing that, the business objects are created just fine, but the object exposing the method to call the web service cannot be created.

The message is:

```
Error occurred while creating/connecting to automation server for: My.ClassName

Error code: 0x80131500 C:\PROGRESS\WRK\my.ped (5894)
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't, try registering the dll's using regasm.

Answer (score 0):

There are many entries in the Progress kbase (http://progress.atgnow.com/esprogress/Group.jsp?bgroup=progress) that seem possibly relevant.  This one comes up #1:

ID: 21285
Title: "Error 5894 When Trying To Start AppBuilder"
Created: 08/27/2001     Last Modified: 03/22/2010
Status: Verified

Symptoms:
Error when attempting to start the AppBuilder.
Error occurred while creating/connecting to automation server for: .
Error occurred while creating/connecting to automation server for: PROX.PROIDE.
Cannot find the module.
Error code: 0x8007007e initialize_uib adeuib/_uibmain.p (5894)

Facts:
Windows
Progress 9.x
OpenEdge 10.x

Cause:
The Prox.Dll file has not been properly registered.

Fixes:
Register the dll by typing the following at the command prompt:

regsvr32 \dlc\bin\prox.dll

If the full path to the file is not specified, the following error will appear:

LoadLibrary ("\prox.dll") Failed.
GetLastError returns 0x0000007e.

If this error is encountered, make sure that the full and correct path to the dll is specified.

Notes:
On Windows 2008 or Windows 7 it is advisable to open the command prompt windows using the "Run as Administrator" option.  Error occurred while creating/connecting to automation server for: .